# Can I use shared preference in an android service?

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-service, sharedpreferences

I have an android application that contains some android background service which work after device boots up without running the app and the service sends notifications to the user.  I need some details about the last login to the application (the last entered user name and password) to engage with the service code .

By the way, I am using shared preference in the login page to store user name and  password for the last person logged in, so can I use these shared preferences to get the username and password from them in the service while the app is not running?

I have tried to do it and this is my code from the android service ...

```
    saveLog = loginPref.getBoolean("saveLog", false);
    String userName = "";
    String passWord = "";

    if (saveLog == true) {
        userName =loginPref.getString("username", "");
        passWord =loginPref.getString("password", "");
    }
```

Here is the login activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butLogin);
    log.setOnClickListener(this);
    loginPref = getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefEditor = loginPref.edit();
    editUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEB);
    editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passEB);
    saveCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.saveCB);

    saveLog = loginPref.getBoolean("saveLog", false);

    if (saveLog == true) {
        editUsername.setText(loginPref.getString("username", ""));
        editPassword.setText(loginPref.getString("password", ""));
        saveCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Here, I store the value of these shared preferences from the Login Activity

```
        if (saveCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefEditor.putBoolean("saveLog", true);
            loginPrefEditor.putString("username", username);
            loginPrefEditor.putString("password", password);
            loginPrefEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefEditor.clear();
            loginPrefEditor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: Yes it will work. Did you try and it didnot worked?

Comment: Yes I have tried the code above and it is not working @sankyjain
the biggest problem is I just learnt about shard preferences today so not familiar with any thing

Comment: Where are you saving the value in shared preference, please show that code

Comment: done, I updated it @sankyjain

Comment: Why are using saveCheckBox.isChecked() try once removing it and check if you get value from shared preference

Comment: This block in the login page and I have to see if the check box of (save user and pass) is ticked or not, my shared preferences are working fine at the login, but I need to get benefit from them at the service only @sankyjain

Comment: Share your service code, how you are getting preference object in service class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106302/discussion-between-sanky-jain-and-hussein).

Comment: make sure you have saved SharedPreferences to file and give file's name: "loginPref" correct in your service.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do , my working code here :

```
mLoginPreferences=getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You can put variables to prefs , clear prefs etc.. whatever you want.

Don't forget this : services is like activites but they running on background.

Comment: Unfortunately I am very beginner with these topics, Can you please set this line of code to my case because I have no idea how to read 2 variables.

Comment: if you can post your service code i can help you man . you can use this site : https://codeshare.io/

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I have sorted my code out and it works brilliant now.